# Convert EditText Array to String Array - Kotlin Android

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-edittext, kotlin

I have an array of EditTexts that I would like to get converted into an Array of Strings containing the input values of each of the EditTexts. Here is my code:

```
val textFields = arrayOf<EditText>(dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_name),
            dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_address), dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_phoneNo),
            dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_amount), dialogView.findViewById(R.id.et_remark))
```

How do I get a String Array of the values of the EditTexts with minimal code?

**Edit:** Basically I want to fit the code as an argument in a function. I would prefer to have it done without using a for-loop. Perhaps an inline function that would give out an array transforming (as given in the function block) each element (EditText) of the original one to a string. I couldn't find any method so far (although it might turn out to be something obvious).

I also need to use it as a `vararg` parameter.

Comment: I think people have downvoted cause you did not provide/show any attempt or research effort. Is a for-loop not enough minimal ?

Comment: @vincrichaud Yes, I agree with your comment. I do think so.

Comment: @vincrichaud minimal enough to fit as a parameter in a function. I'll edit the original question.

Comment: Perfectly valid question now, +1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo this you have to map it into a string array by doing the following:

```
val newTextFieldStringArray = textFields.map { it.text.toString() }
Log.e("TEST", newTextFieldStringArray.toString()) // print it out
```

**Note:**
The map function returns a List. If you'd like to use it as a `vararg` parameter, you can achieve that using `toTypedArray()` and a spread operator `*`. Code As follows:

```
val varargArray = textFields.map { it.text.toString() }.toTypedArray()
myFunction(*varargArray)

private fun myFunction(vararg list: String) {}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. Also, I need to mention, I'm using `varargs` as a parameter. So also should mention that use case.